# Parsing an html content with simple html dom plugin: how to verify if an element has (among its classes) a specific class?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a table with several rows and each row has three cells. Each cell has several classes but only a few of these has a specific class. here is an example of this table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="one two three **oooops**"></td>
    <td class="one two three"></td>
    <td class="one two three"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one two three"></td>
    <td class="one two three **oooops**"></td>
    <td class="one two three"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one two three **oooops**"></td>
    <td class="one two three"></td>
    <td class="one two three **oooops**"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can reach each cell with a foreach loop but how to check if the cell has the class "oooops"?

```
foeach($html->find("tr td") as $td){
  if($td has the class "oooops"){
    do_something
  }
}
```

Comment: `strpos($td->getAttribute('class'), 'oooops') !== 0`?

Comment: @MarcB mmmhh, strange: it seems to be logic but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @MarcB but, with ` strpos($td->getAttribute('class'), 'oooops') !== false ` it works!